# Why is there a difference in potential across a component (potential difference)

Tags: electricity, charge, potential, electrical-resistance

I understand that potential difference is the difference in the potential across a component.

This is the difference in the amount of (work) energy it takes for charge to be moved across the component.

(and the work energy can be explained as components having resistance so energy is needed to move the charge).

**1. Is the above correct?**

So I am wondering why is there a difference in the *amount of (work) energy* it takes for charge to be moved *across the component*

Is it because some of the charge is given to the component (the amount depending on the conductivity of the component ??) so the amount of (work) energy it takes for the charge to be moved decreases as there is less charge??

**2. Why is there a difference in the amount of (work) energy?**

*If this question has been answered please link it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the difference in the amount of (work) energy it takes for
> charge to be moved across the component.

The potential difference between two points ***is*** the amount of work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points, ***not the difference*** in the amount of work.

Hope this helps.